# How to get "Hour" of the day in Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a Script, which I want to NOT run during an interval of the day (since I have other scripts operating on the sheet during that time frame). I want to insert one line of code at the beginning of my function which will just perform a quick check whether the current time of the day is in that time interval or not, but I am unable to do so. Here is the code:
//This the code block which will prevent night time running

```
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours(); if(hours.toString().length==1){var hours = '0'+hours;}

Logger.log(hours);
  if ((hours >= 1) || (hours <= 6))
    return;
```

// Basically making the code not run at night time

But this is giving errors. The time is coming in UTC even when explicitly time zone is mentioned. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not receiving the expected result is due to the fact that the `appsscript.json` manifest file is the one who is holding the information regarding the timezone for your script.

Moreover, the `getHours` method as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) does not expect any parameters, so the `timezone` mentioned there won't do much.

To see the manifest file, you will have to **Project Settings** in the script project and then tick the box which says *Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor*. Afterwards, edit the file such that the timezone of the script is `timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'`.

#### Reference

- [Date.prototype.getHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours);
- [Apps Script Manifests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem in an instant. And for people looking for a code to achieve the problem, the above code can be used. It works fine. As pointed out by @ale13 there is no need to pass timezone in getHours (since arguments are not taken by getHours).